# How to deal with the warning message: package 'rainbow' is not available (for R veraion 3.6.3)?

Tags: r, version, install.packages

I tried to install the package "rainbow":

```
install.packages("rainbow")
```

I got the warning message:

```
package 'rainbow' is not available (for R version 3.6.3)
```

How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: On the CRAN page of `rainbow` ([here](https://cran.univ-lyon1.fr/CRAN/web/packages/rainbow/)), you can see that it depends on R ≥ 4.0.0 so it's not possible to use this package with your version of R. You have two options: 1) find an alternative to this package, 2) update your version of R

Comment: Although I would tend to agree with @bretauv that the best solution here is to update R, there is another solution, which is to do: `devtools::install_version('rainbow', version = '3.6')`. This is an older version of `rainbow` which should be compatible with your version of R

Comment: @AllanCameron if I'm not mistaken, the `version` argument is for the package version you want to install, so you'd still to know when this requirement of R 4.0.0 was implemented (not impossible but almost for a beginner)

Comment: @bretauv you are right - but the previous version of rainbow by coincidence happens to be version 3.6, and is compatible with R version 3.4 and above.